# How do I calculate $\int \tan^{-1}x\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried integration by parts and I got to:

$x tan^{-1} x × \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} × \dfrac{x^2}{2} - \displaystyle\int \tan^{-1}x ×\dfrac{x^2}{2}\,dx$

now that gets even worse…

Comment: You made an error by integrating $dx$ again, check that out.

Answer (score 2):

After doing integration by parts with $u=\arctan x$ and $dv=dx$, you should get
$$ \int\arctan x\;dx= x\arctan(x)-\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}\;dx $$
and the last integral can be evaluated using the substitution $u=1+x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int{\arctan x dx}$

Using the LIATE rule for the choice of $u$

Let $u = \arctan x \implies du = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} dx$

and $dv = 1 dx \implies v = x$

$\displaystyle \int{\arctan x dx} = x\arctan x  - \int{\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}dx}$

$\displaystyle \implies \int{\arctan x dx} = x\arctan x - \dfrac{1}{2}\ln|1+x^2|+C$